# Virtual Hosting - Primary Domain configuration

Tags: configuration, hosting, virtual, web-development-server

I have a technical question about how virtual hosting Primary Domain configuration work.

My client have a hosting plan where I work on the new version of his site, so far no domain point to this hosting, so I had to modified my hosts files to emulate the DNS.

In the Hosting provider details, I have the address ab-cd.com (fake address, just for this question) listed under 'Hosted Domain', which is good, since this is the client domain for his actual site.

However, when I click to connect into the Panelbox / cpanel, the configuration is made for abcd.com (without the dash) an address that my client do not own, in fact, the second address is still available to be buyed.

So, when I ask the technical support to reconfigure the hosting to use the proper address (ab-cd.com) they answer me :

*We can't change the primary domain to ab-cd.com because this domain
is already used on another server.*

However, they can configure their server with an address nobody own. 
How this is possible ?

The problem I fear is, my wordpress installation is configure with abcd.com, so that means I will have to reconfigure when the DNS will be change and finally the server configuration will use the correct domain ab-cd.com, leaving no time for handling any issue that might create. I thought working with a development server was to prevent this kind of situation...

Thanks for helping me to better understand how this things works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a new answer from the technical support, that clarify the situation a little bit.

*The domain ab-cd.com is already configured on our servers, and we
can't use it again, because of a DNS restrictions.*

This answer, of course, make more sens then the first one.
Now, it's a matter to understand how they did configure the things.

I will keep you posted, so at least someone can learn from this experience, once it will be solved.

/* Answer for this issue */

Finally, The mystery unfold. 
The site live version of ab-cd.com was host by iweb.com
The developpement site of ab-cd.com was host by funio.com
These 2 compagnies are the same, and use the same servers.

This information wasn't cleary communicate, creating the confusion on my side. And that's why, they wasn't able to configure the server with the correct address ab-cd.com, so I can use modified hosts files to preview my site, even if they was able to do it for any other address of my choice, even the one that was not my own.

Hope that will help someone who might find itself in a similar situation.

Thanks